# Is "I could not thank you enough." just the past tense of "I cannot thank you enough." or what?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, subjunctives

My quick Google search for "***I cannot thank you enough.***" returned a lot more results than for "***I could not thank you enough.***"

- I cannot thank you enough.  (6,030,000 results)
- I could not thank you enough. (448,000 results)

My questions are:

1. Is "***I could not thank you enough.***" just the past tense of "***I cannot thank you enough.***"?
2. If the answer for the above is No, then when do you use "***I could not thank you enough.***" rather than "***I cannot thank you enough.***"?

Comment: It's the past tense, in terms of grammar.  2) Even going by 'No', since 'thanks' follows (usually) something done, it holds good. E.g., For the kind of your support I couldn't thank you enough.

Comment: I always think of it as a hypothetical/subjunctive - I couldn't thank you enough (e.g. if I lived to be 1000 and spent all that time thanking you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Could* (like *would*) has two different uses.

1. It functions as the past of *can*.

> He said "I can't thank you enough" -> He said he couldn't thank me enough.

2. It is a modal in its own right, with the sense of possibility (not ability, like *can*). In this sense, it is often in conditionals, and counterfactuals.

So

> I couldn't thank you enough (when you said that).

with past meaning, is a straightforward past tense of *I can't thank you enough*.

With present meaning, it would probably be interpreted as something like

> (Even if I thanked you all day) I couldn't thank you enough.

In that sense it sounds very effusive and over the top, and is much less common than "I can't thank you enough".

Comment: Thanks. In case it is used in conditionals, you described it "it sounds very effusive and over the top". Do you think English learners like me should avoid using "I couldn't thank you enough" unless I am fully sure that the expression would perfectly fit in a conversation? To be honest, I thought "I couldn't thank you enough" is a kind of more polite way of expressing my feeling than "I can't thank you enough".

Comment: Its tentativeness (because of the implied conditional) may be seen as making it more polite, but in my view that tentativeness is excessive, and I would not recommend using it. _I can't thank you enough_ though common, is **already** hyperbole.

Comment: You also encounter "I can't/couldn't tell you" (I don't know) and "I can't/couldn't comment" (I am not allowed to answer) - here, inserting "possibly" before "comment" is often taken to mean that the speaker really agrees with the questioner but is prevented, by e.g. protocol, from explicitly saying so.

Answer (score 1):

"Could not" is *imperfect tense*. It can mean the past, or some ongoing condition:

- I tried, but I couldn't lift it (past tense)
- I couldn't lift that, it looks too heavy for me (ongoing)

As your search has proved, "*I cannot thank you enough*" is the most idiomatic use of this phrase. It is hyperbole, but literally means that you are so grateful, no amount of thanks you could offer would express fully your appreciation. Saying "I *could* not thank you enough" would mean almost the same, except you are saying that you could *never* thank the person enough.

You could use the phrase referring to a past act, for example:

> My friend gave me this gift last week. I couldn't thank *him* enough.

The use of "couldn't" here is correct because the act was in the past. You may have said to your friend at the time "I *can't* thank *you* enough".